# give required field validator to radio buttons

Tags: c#, radio-button

this is my html code in which i have used two radio buttons and i want a required field validator which will force a user to select atleast one radio button .

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="enterType" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select Type
  </label>    
<div class="col-sm-10">
     <asp:RadioButton ID="rbEncryption" runat="server" 
     GroupName="grpEncryption" Text="Encryption (e.g. welcome!, Enter 
     plain text)" />
</div>
     <label for="enterType" class="col-sm-2 control-label" >
     </label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
     <asp:RadioButton ID="rbDecryption" runat="server" 
     GroupName="grpEncryption" Text="Decryption (e.g. welcome!, Enter 
     Encrypted text)" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you really need validation? If you pre-select one option the user cannot deselect.

Comment: well yes, should have thought like that ...thank you